# Issue in date format of UIDatePicker during Globalisation

Tags: ios, iphone, globalization, uidatepicker

I am globalizing my project and i have issue in date picker format. My project has to support spanish language. But the users are from US. So when the language is set to spanish, the date picker shows its content in spanish and the format becomes mm/dd/yyyy. But since the users are from US, i need the format to be in dd/mm/yyyy only.. How can i achieve this.?

And my code is,

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es_ES"];
datePicker.locale = locale;
datePicker.calendar = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
```

[image]

Comment: If you want US Spanish then use the locale of `es_US`.

Comment: @rmaddy: if i use es_US as u said, the datePicker language changes to spanish but the format of the date picker remains dd/mm/yyyy.. My requirement is, the language has to be spanish, but the format has to be mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @ManojEllappan your initial question and your comment to rmaddy are contradictory in the requirements you state

Comment: I just did a quick test. Setting the region format to US Spanish gives me a date picker just like above in the picture. I think this is because Spanish dates are in the form `dd MMM yyyy`. But if you format an `NSDate` using an `NSDateFormatter` set to the "Short" style, you do get `MM/dd/yy` as desired. The `UIDatePicker` shows dates in the "Long" style which isn't always the same order as the "Short" style.

Comment: This is default format of `UIDatePicker`'s `NSLocale`.

Comment: @rmaddy: So u say that, in this case, we cant change the format of the datePicker to MM/dd/YYYY right friend?